# GWT: How do I read an Excel file that is included in my src folder?

Tags: eclipse, excel, gwt

I am trying to program in GWT (using Eclipse and the GWT Designer). I would like to be able to take an Excel file that I have already imported into my source folder, read it, and process the data. The data will be both text and numbers, but I am comfortable doing the conversions from String to other types.

I have seen something about RequestBuilder, but I'm not sure how to use that to read Excel. Or, is there another/better way to do this?

I am willing to convert the Excel file into something like a CSV is that is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to do the processing in your servlet with something like

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
or 
http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: JExcelAPI says its just in Java--does GWT support this? Also, I'm doing just about all of the coding for client-side. Is there a tutorial you might suggest about servlets (since I don't know what I would use one for)?

Comment: No, you have to do the processing on the server side.. Javascript can't handle it. If you convert the file to CSV then you could load it as a text resource (check out ClientBundle docs). But as to the servlet stuff, check out these docs: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Comment: Ok, so I can code this in the "server" package included in the source? And then compile/run the app?

Comment: Yeah, your servlets can do anything allowed in Java.. no GWT emulation restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is clear enough to you, but it is **not** possible to process the excel file in **GWT** at least not directly.
You **have** to process it on the backend/server.
It **can't** be done on he client side because even if you put the excel file in your source folder it is not available to the GWT compiled javascript code on the client machine.
If you use Java on your backend/server you can use one of the libraries **danb** suggested to process it on the server and then use RequestFactory or RPC to transmit it to the client/browser for further processing/displaying.